# Can't update table stored trigger , it's already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

i have a users table which keeps the users info and it's last_activity column is getting update to every time a user sees a page .

```
   public function set_last_activity(){
    global $db;
    $t = time();
    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `last_activity` = '$t'
    WHERE 
   `id` = '$this->id'  ";
   $db->query($sql);   
   }
```

each user could have 3 types
1 - employee or ee for short 
2 - employer or er
3 - both types

and status field is :
0 : banned , not active 
1 : active

now i have trigger  and it's handling user counters

(ee_counter for employes [ type:1,3 ] , er_counter for employer  [ type:2,3 ] )

in stats table when a user changes it's status (0 : banned , 1 : active ) and also it updates specialties counter in case the user is employe

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER user_status_change
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE stats s 

 SET

    ee_counter =
      CASE 

        WHEN  (NEW.type= 1 || NEW.type= 3 )   && OLD.status !=1 && NEW.status  = 1  THEN ee_counter + 1
        WHEN  (NEW.type= 1 || NEW.type= 3 )   && OLD.status = 1 && NEW.status != 1  THEN ee_counter - 1

        WHEN  NEW.type= 3  && OLD.type  = 2   THEN ee_counter + 1
        WHEN  OLD.type= 1  && NEW.type  = 2   THEN ee_counter - 1
        ELSE ee_counter 
      END ,

    er_counter =
      CASE 
        WHEN  (NEW.type= 2 || NEW.type= 3 )   && OLD.status !=1 && NEW.status  = 1  THEN er_counter + 1
        WHEN  (NEW.type= 2 || NEW.type= 3 )   && OLD.status = 1 && NEW.status != 1  THEN er_counter - 1

        WHEN  NEW.type= 3  && OLD.type = 1   THEN er_counter + 1
        WHEN  OLD.type= 2  && NEW.type = 1   THEN er_counter - 1
        ELSE er_counter 
      END 

  WHERE
    s.id = 1;


  UPDATE specialitys s 
JOIN speciality_objects o
      ON s.id = o.speciality_id
    JOIN users u
      ON o.user_id = u.id
 SET
    counter =
      CASE 
        WHEN  NEW.status = 1  && OLD.status !=1 THEN counter + 1
        WHEN  NEW.status != 1 && OLD.status = 1 THEN counter - 1
         ELSE counter 
      END 

  WHERE
  o.user_id = NEW.id &&  s.id = o.speciality_id ;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

it used to work fine until i changed my host and bought a vps

no i keep on getting this error

```
Database query failed: Can't update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

on every page when i update the last_activity

i tried to use BEFORE UPDATE as some has suggested it didn't work still getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error is caused by a part of the last `UPDATE` query within the trigger that is pointless anyway.

The error message is complaining because of this part of the query:

```
JOIN users u
  ON o.user_id = u.id
```

...you have `JOIN`ed the table that the trigger is attached to, onto an `UPDATE` query within the trigger. MySQL is correctly spotting that this could result in a recursion, and throwing an error.

You should, however, be able to simply remove that part of the query. The alias `u` is not used anywhere, so the `JOIN` is unnecessary. I think this will fix the problem.